# How can I compare a prefab and GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
prefab = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Prefab", prefab, typeof(GameObject), false);

        GUI.enabled = false;
        var selection = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToList();
        for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            selectedObject = selection[i];
            if (prefab != null && selection.Count > 0
                && prefab != selectedObject)
                GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Replace"))
        {
            selection = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToList();

            if (prefab != null && selection.Count > 0)
            {
                for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                {
                    var selected = selection[i];
                    SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(selected.scene.name));

                    var prefabType = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType(prefab);
                    GameObject newObject;

                    if (prefabType == PrefabType.Prefab)
                    {
                        newObject = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefab);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newObject = Instantiate(prefab);
                        newObject.name = prefab.name;
                    }

                    if (newObject == null)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("Error instantiating prefab");
                        break;
                    }

                    Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(newObject, "Replace With Prefabs");
                    newObject.transform.parent = selected.transform.parent;
                    newObject.transform.localPosition = selected.transform.localPosition;
                    newObject.transform.localRotation = selected.transform.localRotation;
                    newObject.transform.localScale = selected.transform.localScale;
                    newObject.transform.SetSiblingIndex(selected.transform.GetSiblingIndex());
                    Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(selected);
                }
            }
        }
```

I want that the button will be enable true also only if the prefab is not the same as the selected object/s.

First time I select one or more objects then click on Replace now it's replacing the selected objects with the prefab. But if I select again the replaced objects it still enable true the button. But they should be the same as the prefab and not to enable true the button.

This is the comparison I'm trying to do:

```
prefab != selectedObject
```

Comment: You want to compare two GameObjects or two prefabs? Maybe you want to check if a GameObject instance in the Hierarchy came from prefab?

Comment: What I want to do is after replacing a selected gameobject with a prefab don't allowed to replace it again only if the selected gameobject is not replaced yet by the prefab. If I select in the hierarchy a already replaced gameobject enable false the button. If the selected gameobject/s not replaced yet enable true the button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They aren't the same because `!=` in C# used between two reference types that don't have the equality operator overloaded will do a reference comparison. This means that it will check whether the variable refers to the same underlying object instance. So `prefab != selectedObject` will *only* evaluate to false if prefab and selectedObject are the exact same object instance (iirc it checks an object ID for equality).

As far as I gather you want it to evaluate to false and therefore activate the button if and only if the selected objects aren't clones of prefab. Luckily Unity3D has a way of telling whether a GameObject is instantiated from a specific prefab. It's called [PrefabUtility
                .GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetPrefabObject.html). So this might fit your requirements:

Change this part:

```
for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    selectedObject = selection[i];
    if (prefab != null && selection.Count > 0
        && prefab != selectedObject)
        GUI.enabled = true;
}
```

To this:

```
for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    var selectedObject = selection[i];
    if (prefab != null && selection.Count > 0
        && prefab != PrefabUtility
        .GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource(selectedObject))
        GUI.enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: This code is inside OnGUI and therefore the loop is running over and over again nonstop. The script is EditorWindow and working when the game is not running. Does it fine to make the loop running over and over again or it's too expensive for memory/cpu usage ?

Comment: It depends on your usage. It can be too expensive if combined with a lot of other Inspector code that runs in a loop. By its own it's very unlikely to slow down your editor, but with other stuff it can add up. It won't ever affect the game's performance in a build, of course. If you want to make it more performant then you can use the ``Selection.selectionChanged`` event to run your loop only when the selection has actually changed.

Comment: Can you show me please an example how to use the Selection.selectionChanged event with one loop like my code and another example if I have for example 3 loops in some places inside the OnGU ? Or how do I check in inside the Selection.selectionChanged if the selection has changed ?

Comment: Actually I found out that EditorWindow has an easier way to do this. Instead of using the ``Selection.selectionChanged`` event there's a special ``OnSelectionChange()`` method that you can use the same way you use ``Awake()`` or ``Update()``. So you create a bool that tracks if the selection recently changed and set it to true in ``OnSelectionChange()`` and force an onGUI update. Then you do your code in the onGUI and set the variable to false. I've created a minimal example for you here: https://paste.debian.net/1040079/

Comment: Let me show you what I did. I'm getting exception in the Editor: ArgumentException: You can only call GUI functions from inside OnGUI. https://pastebin.com/B4AJWzQq

Comment: I'm getting the exception on the first line in the OnGUI: GUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);

Comment: And another thing I saw there is a method you can call repaint: private void OnInspectorUpdate()
 {
  Repaint();
 } Does it do the same thing as calling OnGUI from the OnSelectionChange or it's not the same thing ?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. It seems that calling OnGUI directly is something that Unity3D doesn't like. It only worked for me because I wasn't calling GUILayout methods. Try replacing the ``OnGUI()`` call in ``OnSelectionChange()`` with ``Repaint()``.

Comment: Thank you very much. Working great.

Answer (score 0):

The UnityEngine.Component class does implement a working equality operator (you need to use object.Equals) and we can use reflection to access all the components in both a prefab, and a living instance of that prefab. It is possible, to determine what has changed, but it is not pretty, and there are lots of difficult corner cases to deal with.